# Values in attribute table not showing up

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, csv, table

I have values in an attribute table I want to label my layer with. But when I label it, a totally different set of values show up. In the attribute table, my values are between 0 and 200. But the labels have values as extreme as 300,000. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: You have to tell us what program you are using, what format are your table, etc...

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10. My table is in .csv.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to open the **Properties** of that layer and go to the **Labels** tab where you will probably find that the **Label Field** is not set to the one you think.